# Automated Installation for Debian Jessie

Tags: installation, operating-system, debian, automated-deployment

I have an exisiting automated Installer for Ubuntu based on Kickstart and want to build one for the Debian. In the interest of uniformity using Kickstart seems to be the best option.

a. Can Kickstart be used for the automated installation of Debian?

b. Any merits of using FAI for Debian instead of kickstart?

c. Any solutions thats used and tried as reference will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian you can use "preseed" (https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) to build you automated Debian install ;)